# Trim whitespace and Ignore Hash sign in Solr

Tags: java, php, mysql, solr

I am new to Solr and I am facing problem to "trim white spaces" and in "ignoring hash sign".

For example, If I have following results in my database:

```
"Red Blue abc",  
"abc RedBlue",  
"Red abc Blue",  
"Red abc",  
"Blue abc"
```

Now if search for "RedBlue" i get all of the above but if search for "Red Blue", i am not able to retrieve all of the above results. Some are being missed. Same problem with the hash sign.If I search for "Red#Blue", I am facing the same problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could strip the white spaces and hash tags with `str_replace` or `preg_replace` but that might give different content than what your user expects, no? For example, distinguishing `be fore` vs. `before` won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FULLTEXT feature from MySQL:

1. Create the index on your table:

   ```
   CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX text_index ON your_table(text_field);
   ```
2. Use the fulltext search statement:

   ```
   mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE MATCH(text_field) 
            AGAINST('Red Blue');
   +--------------+
   | text_field   |
   +--------------+
   | Red Blue abc |
   | Red abc Blue |
   | Red abc      |
   | Blue abc     |
   +--------------+
   4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
   ```

You must replace the hash sign before run your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be more about words that may be together or separate during index or search.

In Solr, this is dealt with during Analysis by including a [WordDelimiterFilter](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) in the analyzer chain. You can see [the links to the examples that use it](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#WordDelimiterFilterFactory) on Solr Start. The examples that ship with Solr use that filter too, so make sure to read the tutorial.